# Regular expression for matching pairs

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write regular expression in java for matching pairs (param : value) from specific text:

> "CUSTOMER
>
> ```
> Customer Name               :  JOHN DOE
>
> City                  :  Chicago
>
> Customer Id               :  123AWE32D2
>
> System Id             :  004349
>
> Register Date (yymmddww)      :  12020906
> ```
>
> "

As output I want to have pairs:

> Customer Name, JOHN DOE 
>   City, Chicago 
>   Customer Id, 123AWE32D2
>   System Id, 004349 
>   Register Date (yymmddww), 12020906

There could be various number of parameters. I need to have universal pattern for extracting groups (param name) : (value). Here is my pattern, I wrote for matching specific param:

`\s*Customer Name\s*:\s*([^\n]*\S)`

Comment: We are not here to do your job; have a look at `split`.

Answer (score 2):

1) Use this `(.+):(.+)` in multiline mode.

Meaning:

`.` - anything

`:` - then we need colon

`.` - again anything

`+` - at least one character

You have 2 groups, before colon and after.

2) or simply use `split()` method - `split(":")`

After both, use `trim()` to remove spaces or remove them in regular expression.

Comment: you should rather use non-greedy matching (`(.+?):(.+?)`) in multiline mode.

Comment: In such case, both should work, we have only one `:` in the line.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "multi line" switch `(?m)` that makes ^/$ match after/before newlines:

```
(?m)^\\s*(.+?)\\s*:\\s*(.+?)\\s*$
```

Each match will capture the param name in group 1 and the value in group 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?s)\\b(.+?):(.*?)\\b(.+?)\\n").matcher(your text);
while (m.find())
    System.out.print(m.group(1).trim() + "," + m.group(3).trim() + " ");
```